# How to tell if SIGWINCH has been activated in bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am trying to get it to were if the window size changes in the terminal it redraws a box. I am unsure of how to catch this signal, the documentation I was able to find online was not particularly helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash

SCREEN(){

line=$(tput lines)
col=$(tput cols)

clear
for (( i = 1; i <= $line; i++ )); do
  for (( j = 1; j <= $col; j++ )); do
    if (( 1 == i || $line == i || 1 == j || $col == j )); then
      echo -n "*"
    else
      echo -n " "
    fi
  done
  echo
done
}

SCREEN;
trap SCREEN SIGWINCH
while true; do

if [[ SIGWINCH == "true" ]]; then
sleep 1
SCREEN
fi
done
```

My understanding is to do this trap is needed to get the event of the terminal changing sizes. How do i make it so if SIGWINCH occurs then the logic occurs?

Comment: I think that the trap command should be: `trap SCREEN WINCH`.

Comment: After `trap SCREEN SIGWINCH` or `trap SCREEN WINCH`, `SCREEN` function is called. You don't need to put `if ... fi` statement in the loop. Just put `sleep 1` or what you want. So, `SCREEN` is called you you change the size of your terminal window. Works fine in `gnome-terminal`, `xfce4-terminal` or `terminator` and without doubt with many other.
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html

Comment: I tried that if it under while true do it loops and redraws it every second and if you exclude the while true statement the program just ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Analysis

For me your script kinda works in `tmux` in `konsole` (I just needed to remove the last `echo` from the function to make the whole box stay visible). The script does not work in the way (I think) you think it works though.

Contrary to what one of the comments states, `trap SCREEN SIGWINCH` is a good command. *Portably* it should be `trap SCREEN WINCH`, but for `trap` *in Bash* `SIGWINCH` is as good as `WINCH`.

`[[ SIGWINCH == "true" ]]` returns exit status 1 (failure) because the string `SIGWINCH` is not equal to the string `true`. In effect `sleep 1` and `SCREEN` (that appear after `then`) never run. Your `while` loop only invokes `true` and compares two different fixed strings again and again.

When SIGWINCH comes, the trap works and `SCREEN` gets executed. In my tests the script reacts to changes of the size of its "window" (a tmux pane in my case).

Your `while` loop does nothing by itself, but if not the loop, the script would exit after setting up the trap in vain.

---

#### Improvements

This is a modified script that implements the logic I think you wanted:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCREEN () {
   clear
   for (( i = 1; i <= "$LINES"; i++ )); do
      for (( j = 1; j <= "$COLUMNS"; j++ )); do
         if (( 1 == i || "$LINES" == i || 1 == j || "$COLUMNS" == j )); then
            echo -n "*"
         else
            echo -n " "
         fi
      done
   done
}

trap SCREEN WINCH
SCREEN            # to draw the first box
while true; do
   sleep 1
done
```

Note I removed your calls to `tput`. By default bash sets `LINES` and `COLUMNS` after each external (non-builtin) command. In our case `clear` is the external command that makes the shell update the variables and there is no need to query `tput`.

If you want your script to do something outside of the trap, put it before (or instead of) the `while` loop. Keep in mind the trap (in general: a trap) cannot run when the shell awaits exit of a synchronous command. In our case the trap can run after `true` or after `sleep 1`, but not during; this is why the script does not always immediately redraws the box, there is usually a delay because the shell waits for `sleep 1` to finish. If you introduce a long-running synchronous command then it will similarly make the script stop updating the box until the command finishes. A solution is to run the command asynchronously and `wait` for it. The point is a signal can interrupt `wait`.

The following example script will react to changes of the size of its window virtually immediately:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCREEN () {
   clear
   for (( i = 1; i <= "$LINES"; i++ )); do
      for (( j = 1; j <= "$COLUMNS"; j++ )); do
         if (( 1 == i || "$LINES" == i || 1 == j || "$COLUMNS" == j )); then
            echo -n "*"
         else
            echo -n " "
         fi
      done
   done
}

trap SCREEN WINCH
SCREEN            # to draw the first box
while true; do
   sleep 10 &
   wait
done
```

I could use `tail -f /dev/null &` before the loop ([this command shall never end by itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42905/108618)) and `wait` inside the loop, but in some circumstances `tail` could survive termination of the script and we don't want to let this happen. `sleep 10` has to keep being renewed in the loop, but each instance will exit eventually no matter what. On the other hand a SIGWINCH that interrupts `wait` won't kill any background `sleep`, so if the signals come frequently then the number of background `sleep` processes will increase up to the value of about "number of signals per 10 seconds". In practice SIGWINCH happens occasionally, not all the time, so the problem is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the code always helpful . I tried true with a high confidence it wouldn't work. I left it to help convey the idea of what i wanted to happen. I do plan on using this for something else so ill keep those tips in mind. Thanks again